Do we have an idiom saying a person talks too loudly or often screams?
My 6-year-old daughter often screams or yells at ChatGPT when it doesn't understand her.
Vietnamese people sometimes will say "you're such a big mouth!" (literally translated from Vietnamese) to refer to a person who often talks loudly or screams or yell at other people or things.
I checked "a big mouth" in dictionaries and it means "​a person who talks a lot, especially about him- or herself, and who cannot keep secrets".
I did a study and found these other options:

You're such a loudmouth!

You're such a blabbermouth!

You have such a booming voice!

You shout/scream your head off!


Do we have an idiom saying a person talks too loudly or often screams

A caveat: the existence of an idiom doesn't mean  it should be your first choice.  You could just as well say "Stop shouting at ChatGPT".

Is the young user speaking to the LLM using a microphone and some Speech recognition?  She may not comprehend the difference between this and a telephone call to a real person.

"loudmouth"  Someone who talks too much or loudly especially in an offensive way.
"Blabbermouth" Someone to talks to much, especially telling other peoples secrets.
"Booming" Deep and resonant.  Like an male opera singer who sings the bass part.
"Scream your head off" is about what a person is doing, not about about their personality.
I would just use "loud":

My daughter is so loud. She even shouts at chatgpt.


Stop being loud! You know it's just a computer.


A “big-mouth” is someone who talks about subjects he should leave alone.
Someone who talks literally too loudly (nói to) is a “loud-mouth”.
